# Objective C Sending an NSDate to a ASP.NET crew server via HttpGet

Tags: json, objective-c, asp.net-core

I am trying to send this data to my web server from my iPhone app
productKey is an NSString
and sinceDate is an NSDate

do I build this URL but it crashes when I call this function

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlPath]
completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)

the exception is
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSFrozenDictionaryM _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to

this is how I make the url string

`NSString * urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@?productKey=%ld&itemDate=%@",[ self.viewModel getUrl],@"GetProductUpdates",productKey, sinceDate  ];`

this is the server function

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetProductUpdates(string productKey,DateTime sinceDate)
```

thanks all

Comment: That's not how we present code here.  And "I am trying to send this data to my web server from my iPhone app productKey is an NSString and sinceDate is an NSDate" is not a comprehensable sentence in English.

Comment: Could you print `urlPath`? Is that really the one you want? I wouldn't `sinceDate` as such for instance, I'd use at least a `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: http://ServerUrl/GetProductUpdates?productKey=4242&sinceDate=2021-06-01 13:38:51 +0000

Answer (score 1):

i wrote this function to convert the dates and it worked

```
+(NSString *) nsDateToJSONString:(NSDate *) date
{
    NSISO8601DateFormatter * dateformatter = [[NSISO8601DateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateformatter.formatOptions = NSISO8601DateFormatWithInternetDateTime | NSISO8601DateFormatWithFractionalSeconds;
    return [dateformatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```